# «Мир вдвоём» — можно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, лексика, значение-слов, стилистика

Можно ли говорить **мир вдвоём**?
Например, в таком контексте : "это был их мир вдвоём". Что означает данное словосочетание?

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что сочетание [*мир вдвоём*](http://loveread.ec/contents.php?id=80609) уже есть, оно известно. Такое название использует Антонина Пикуль в своей книге "Валентин Пикуль" (часть третья, глава первая).

> Да, жена писателя, литератора — это профессия, и довольно сложная. Мне нужен секретарь, референт, помощник и друг, который бы меня понимал, разделял мои взгляды и был всегда рядом. Так что всякие разъезды по курортам и заграницам — исключены. Понимаю, что приятно посмотреть мир, но не расстраивайся — *я заменю тебе весь мир!*

[Мир](http://www.endic.ru/dmytriev/Mir-1481.html) — слово многозначное. Это какая-либо сфера жизни, это явления или вещи, которые окружают человека,  это взаимодействие людей друг с другом, это область профессиональной деятельности, это — сама жизнь.
Жизнь вдвоем — мир для двоих — мир вдвоем. Мне нравится такая иносказательность, я ее принимаю.

Вспомнилось у Ахматовой ("Последний тост"):
*Я пью за разорённый дом,

За злую жизнь мою,

За **одиночество вдвоём**,

И за тебя я пью, —

За ложь меня предавших губ,

За мертвый холод глаз,

За то, что мир жесток и груб,

За то, что Бог не спас.*

Comment: А где там это сочетание?

Comment: Сочетание находится по ссылке. Там это название главы. На мой взгляд, все таки сочетание некорректное. "Одиночество вдвоем" звучит, а "мир вдвоем" нет. Дело в том, что мир слово многозначное. В нашем случае имеется в виду материальный объект - вселенная (понятно, что это выражение метафоризованное и трактуется нематериально, но изначально оно должно было быть материальным). Материальный объект не имеет ничего общего с состоянием (одиночество).

Comment: @Серж Я добавила в ответ _местонахождение_ сочетания: часть третья, глава первая.

Comment: "Одиночество" или "жизнь"" - совсем другое (за этим стоят ощущение и действие). Существование же никем не подхваченного оккааионализма меня не убедило. На мой взгляд,, и содержание главы (там даже не о путешествиях) не раскрывает заголовок  такой конструкции, и звучать он продолжает столь же неестественно, как, например, "вокзал вдвоём".

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, у вас "одиночество вдвоем".

Comment: Хотя я не против такого сочетания.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что нельзя составить такое *понятие*. "Вдвоём" может сочетаться с глаголом, отглагольными формами (включая отглагольное существительное, напр. "чаепитие", и даже такое существительное, как "пир", косвенно связанное с *действием*, а не просто с существованием), но не со "статичным" существительным типа "мира". В вашем случае желаемый смысл можно выразить как "**мир двоих**".

Comment: @user190920 мир в глубоком смысле этого слова это состояние души, то что внутри нас, это то, что мы ощущаем посредством восприятия нашим сознанием. То есть тут все выражается в чувствах, а никак не материальном отношении